# Subtraction on database value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I'm having a problem in subtracting the amount inputted by the user to the current stock count. here is my code.

here is some of my code. I have a link in index of `ItemReg` that will open the `withdraw.cshtml` once click then, when the user put a value on the input box the value will be deducted to the database.

**Controller**

```
public IActionResult Withdraw(int? id, int quantity)
     {
          return View(_context.ItemRegs.Find(id));
     }

public async Task<IActionResult> Withdraw([Bind("ItemId,Qty")] ItemReg itemReg,int? id, int quantity) 
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) {

                var itemreg = _context.ItemRegs.Find(id);
                itemreg.Qty = itemreg.Qty - quantity;
                _context.Update(itemReg);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }

            return View(itemReg);
        }
```

**withdraw.cshtml**

```
@model Intranet.Models.ItemReg

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "View";
}

<h4>ItemReg</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="View">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="ItemId" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Qty" class="control-label"></label>
                <input name="quantity" asp-for="Qty" class="form-control"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="Qty" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Comment: what is the error? not subtracting? not showing?

Comment: yup.. when i go back to the index page the value does not change, sir

Comment: Your form's `asp-action` is `View` but your action method is called `Withdraw`. This is incorrect.

Comment: as mentioned by @PriyankPanchal, `asp-action` is not directed to `withdraw`

Comment: I changed it to Withdraw still does not deduct the value inputted.

Comment: which endpoint does it hit on debug? `IActionResult` or `Task<IActionResult`?

Comment: I feel your `int? id` is zero upon passing, can you confirm?

Comment: it went through on both but in the Task<IActionResult> it skip the If statement If(ModelState.IsValid) means the modelstate is invalid

Comment: check last comment and/or answer

Comment: what do you see when you are debugging this?

Comment: in the `Task<IActionResult>` the If (ModelState.IsValid) is false.

Answer (score 0):

You are using id as the source of your `Find(id)`. Try passing `itemReg.ItemId` in your `Find(itemReg.ItemId)` as your hidden field is `ItemId`

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="ItemId" />
```

which is binding in the model is not used, try using your model.Id

```
var itemreg = _context.ItemRegs.Find(itemReg.ItemId);
itemreg.Qty = itemreg.Qty - quantity;
_context.Update(itemReg);
```

Comment: in the input tag if i put the asp-for='IdenId' it will put the current value. the input tag supposed to be blank so that the user put the amount they withdraw.

Comment: the one i am talking is about the `ItemId`. Is your `int? id` zero on passing?

Comment: same thing happens sir. i think the quantity is zero. im not sure if i got the value from the input box properly.

Comment: wait, you havent answered my question, is your `int? id` zero?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is a good practice but this answers my question.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Withdraw([Bind("ItemId,Qty")] ItemReg itemReg,int quantity) 
        {
            ViewBag.qty = quantity;
            //if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                var itemreg = _context.ItemRegs.Find(itemReg.ItemId);
                itemreg.Qty = itemreg.Qty - ViewBag.qty;
                itemReg.UserName = ViewBag.DisplayName;
                itemreg.UserIP = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
                itemreg.UserDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            //}
            //return View(itemReg);
        }
```

I commented the if statement then add the int quantity in the argument.